# How can I display the data after the user submits the form in Laravel 10?

Tags: laravel, forms, routes, show, laragon

**Submission form**

```
<form action="{{route('psm.pengurusan-staf.store')}}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{__('psm::general.passport')}}</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="passport" value="{{$profiles->passport ?? null}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{__('psm::general.nric')}}</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="mykad" value="{{$profiles->mykad ?? null}}">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{__('psm::general.fullName')}}</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{$profiles->name ?? null}}">
    </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id)
{
    $profiles = profiles::where('user_id', $id)->first();

    return view('psm::pengurusan-staf.show');
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('psm/pengurusan-staf/show/{id}', 'PengurusanStafController@show')
    ->name('psm.pengurusan-staf.show');
```

I'm using Laragon for the database. This is what I want the data to show.

**show.blade.php**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{__('psm::general.passport')}}</label>
    <li>{{$profiles->passport ?? null}}</li>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{__('psm::general.nric')}}</label>
    <li>{{$profiles->mykad ?? null}}</li>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{__('psm::general.fullName')}}</label>
    <li>{{$profiles->name ?? null}}</li>
</div>
```

Should I write the form for the route? For example, in theshow.blade.php, do I need to make the...

`<form action="{{route('psm.pengurusan-staf.show')}}" method="POST"> @csrf @method('get') //my show.blade.php </form?`